# infinite input loop until user quits in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, loops

How to take a infinite input loop until he quits in Perl as i am unable to quit from the code properly even after entering quit or q. Your help is highly appreciated.

```
do
 {
 &ipdiscover;
 print "enter q or quit to exit";
  my $input=<>;
  chomp($input);
  if($input=="quit")
  exit;
}until(($input eq "quit")||($input eq "q"));
```

Comment: Why did you use `==` in one conditional and `eq` in the other for strings?

Comment: do
 {
 print "Enter the I.P Adress to look out for Discovery name"."\n";
 &ipdiscover;
 print "enter q  to exit and any other word to continue"."\n";
  my $input=<STDIN>;
  chomp($input);
  #if($input=="quit")
  exit 0 if(($input eq "q")||($input eq "quit"));
}until(($input eq "quit")||($input eq "q"));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&ipdiscover` – never call functions like that, except when you know about all the side effects. If in doubt, do `ipdiscover()`.

Do not compare strings with the `==` operator: That coerces the arguments to numbers. If it doesn't look like a number, you get zero. So `$input == "quit"` is very likely true for most `$input`s.

However, the `if` statement is defined in terms of blocks, not in terms of statements (as in C). Therefore, you have to do

```
if ($input eq "quit") {
  exit;
}
```

Or a shorthand: `exit if $input eq "quit";`. But why would you want to do that? `exit` terminates the whole program.

On the other hand, `until(($input eq "quit")||($input eq "q"))` is a correct termination condition, and would work as expected once you fix the scope of `$input`.

I think you should rather do the following, because this handles the end of input better (e.g. on Linux: a Ctrl-D, Windows; Ctrl-Z):

```
use strict; use warnings; # put this at the top of every program!

while(defined(my $answer = prompt("type q or quit to exit: "))) {
  last if $answer eq "q"
       or $answer eq "quit"
}

sub prompt {
  my ($challenge) = @_;
  local $| = 1;  # set autoflush;
  print $challenge;
  chomp( my $answer = <STDIN> // return undef);
  return $answer;
}
```

You can leave a loop by saying this was the `last` iteration.